# to access jqtransform select using keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jqtransform for combo-box. I need to access the select using keyboard. For eg: to access the option of select-jqtransform using arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant selecting the combobox options by arrow keys, here is my solution:

HTML:

```
<select id="IdOfCombobox">
    <option value="0">Option1</option>
    <option value="1">Option2</option>
    <option value="2">Option3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
var numberOfOptions= $("#IdOfCombobox > option").length;
var selectedIndex = $("#IdOfCombobox option:selected").val();

switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 38: // UP Key
        if(selectedIndex > 0){
            $("#IdOfCombobox").val(parseInt($("#IdOfCombobox option:selected").val()) - 1);   
        }
        break;
    case 40: // DOWN Key
        if(selectedIndex < numberOfOptions - 1){
            $("#IdOfCombobox").val(parseInt($("#IdOfCombobox option:selected").val()) + 1);   
        }
        break;
}
```

});